# Baer-levi semigroup and Green's Relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

> **Definition 1:** Let $X$ be a countably infinite set and let $B$ be the set of one-to-one maps $\alpha: X\to X$ with the property that $X\setminus X\alpha$ is infinite. Then $B$ with composition is the *Baer-Levi semigroup*.
>
> **Definition 2:** We call $S$ *right simple* if $\mathcal R=S\times S$, and *left simple* if $\mathcal L=S\times S$, where $\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal L$ are Green's $R$- and $L$-relation, respectively.
>
> **Definition 3:** We call $S$ *right cancellative* if $(\forall a, b, c\in S) ac=bc\implies a=b$, and *left cancellative* if $(\forall a, b, c\in S) ca=cb\implies a=b$.

### The Question:

> Show that the Baer-Levi semigroup $B$ is right simple and right cancellative, but is neither left simple nor left cancellative.

Let $\alpha, \beta \in B$. Then $\alpha \mathcal R \beta$ iff there exist $\gamma, \delta \in B$ such that
$$\alpha = \beta \gamma \; , \; \beta = \alpha \delta$$

we need to show that $ \mathcal R = B \times B$. Let $\alpha, \beta \in B$, then define $\gamma : X \rightarrow X$ such that

$$ y \gamma = \begin{cases} x \alpha & \text{if} \; y\; \in \text{im}\beta ; x\beta = y \\
a_y  & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ 
where $a_y \notin$ im$\beta$ is fixed such that $a_y = a_{y'}$ iff $y = y'$.

Cleary $\gamma$ is a one-one mapping. How to prove $X\backslash X\gamma$ is infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a, b \in B$. Since the sets $X \setminus Xa$ and $X \setminus Xb$ are countable infinite, there exists an injective function $h$ from $X \setminus Xa$ into $X \setminus Xb$ such that the set $F = (X \setminus Xb) \setminus (X \setminus Xa)h$ is
infinite. We now define $c$ as follows: for each $q \in X$,
$$
  q c = \begin{cases}
   p b & \text{if $q = pa$ for some $p \in X$,} \\
  q h & \text{if $q \in X \setminus Xa$}
 \end{cases}
$$
By construction, $c$ is injective and $ac = b$. Furthermore, the set $X
\setminus Xc$ contains $F$ and hence is infinite. Thus $c \in B$ and $\mathcal{R}$ is the universal relation on $B$.

Comment: Thanks for giving me your precious time.  I also got into trouble to show that $B$ is not left simple and it does not hold left cancellative law.

Comment: @ J.-E : Suppose $\mathcal L = B \times B$ and $a, b \in S$, then  $\exists c, c' \in  B$ such that $ a= cb$ and $b = c'a$, then $ a  = cc'a$. We get $xcc' = x$, since $a$ is one-one map. Similarly $c'c = I_d$ on $X$. Thus $c, c'$ is bijective, we get a contradiction. Am I right .

Comment: Please ask your questions separately, not in a comment.