# How to prove that in a semigroup, two $\mathcal{L}$ classes in a $\mathcal{D}$ class are incomparable by $\leq_{\mathcal{L}}$ relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid, greens-relations

Let $S$ be a semigroup. I would like to prove that two $L$ classes (namely $L_1$ and $L_2$) such that both are in a $D$ class (that is $L_1\subseteq D$ and $L_2 \subseteq D$) are incomparable by $\leq_{L}$ relation.
I am interested in the proof in cases when $S$ is 
(a) infinite
(b) finite.

Comment: What is $\le_L$-relation? What did you try?

Comment: $x \leq_L y \iff \exists z, x=zy \iff S^1x\subseteq S^1y$

Comment: What is an $L$ class? What is a $D$ class?

Comment: For more explanation please refer to [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations).

Comment: What did you try? This looks like a homework exercise.

Comment: @markvs I wanted to prove that $x \leq_{L} y \land x\mathcal D y \implies x\mathcal L y$. So, I have $x=zy, x=myn, y=pxq$ for some $z,m,n,p,q \in S^1$. So, $y=pzyq$, so by simplification lemma $y \mathcal{L} zy$, so $y\mathcal{L} x$. But simplification lemma only works for finite semigroups? Does this result hold for infinite semigroups? Is there another proof which by passes simplification lemma?

Comment: @PrimeMover As you can see, the question refers to the tag "greens-relations", so a minimum knowledge on this [notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations) is required to understand this question.

Comment: @markvs A homework exercise, really? I wonder how many students could solve it from scratch.

Comment: You need to include it in the question. Otherwise the question has no context. Also add info about the source of the problem. Did you make it up yourself? Also $D=J$ is wrong for infinite  semigroups.

Comment: The question already seems to be complete.

Comment: For finite semigroups the statement is a trivial corollary of  the Rees-Sushkevich theorem and must be an exercise in a semigroup theory course. For infinite semigroups it is not that trivial but clearly doable (my guess is that the answer is negative).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Yeah, I understand it seems to be a prevalent philosophy on this site that "if you don't understand the notation you have no business learning anything from such a question" but that smacks to me of the sort of elitist gatekeeperism that continues to render mathematics ever more inaccessible to the uninitiated. If this point of view is offensive to anyone, then I'm afraid I am unapologetic.

Comment: @prime-mover I feel sorry for your reaction, so let me clarify my point. I just pointed the role of the tags on this site.  For instance, for a question tagged *complex analysis*, OPs expect you to know the definition of a holomorphic function. This has nothing to do "render mathematics ever more inaccessible to the uninitiated", but it is a useful indication of the background needed to fully understand the question. That said, a pointer to wikipedia is often welcome, I agree with you on this point.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Well okay, I suppose that on this website the tag concept puts it into some sort of appropriate context, but it does compromise such a question's portability. At the other extreme, one bizarrely is expected to cite the complete publishing details of any book referenced, however well-known or accessible such a work is, or one's question is in danger of being peremptorily closed. No matter, I will in future assume that any question which uses unfamiliar notation is going to be well over my head.

Comment: @PrimeMover: That is not exactly correct. This particular question is very badly formulated. The person asking a question  is supposed to make the question as clear as possible. For example, I know what Green relations are but I have never seen the notation $\le_ L$ (that relation is not a partial order!). And I have never heard about the simplification lemma.

Comment: @markvs The notation $\leq_{L}$ is defined in the mentioned [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations) page of green's relations. Also, I have not mentioned any lemma in the question.

Comment: @AJ: I do not know who wrote the Wikipedia article and have not read it. When I learned this stuff there was no Internet. It is quite possible that I know more about Green relations than whoever wrote the article. I asked you to add context to the question. You did post a comment instead (you never disclosed the source of the question, though).  So I treat that comment as a part of the question. The lemma is in that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**.
This property holds in any *stable* semigroup and hence in particular in any finite semigroup and in any compact semigroup.

It does not hold for instance in the [Baer-Levi semigroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353282/baer-levi-semigroup-and-greens-relation).

**Definition**.

A $\cal J$-class $J$ is *left* [*right*] *stable* if, for every $s, t \in J$, $s \leqslant_{\cal L} t$ implies that $s \mathrel{\cal L}  t$ [$s \leqslant_{\cal R}  t$ implies that $s \mathrel{\cal R} t$]. A $\cal J$-class $J$ is *stable* if it is both right and left stable. Finally a semigroup is *stable* if each of its $\cal J$-classes is stable.

In a stable semigroup, the Green's relations $\cal J$ and $\cal D$
are equal. Furthermore, the following properties hold:

1. if $s = usv$ for some $u, v\in S^1$, then $us \mathrel{\cal H} s \mathrel{\cal H} sv$;
2. If $s \mathrel{\cal J} t$ and $s \leqslant_{\cal R} t$ $[s \leqslant_{\cal L} t]$, then $s \mathrel{\cal R} t$
   $[s \mathrel{\cal L} t]$;
3. If $s \leqslant_{\cal J} sx$, then $s \mathrel{\cal J} sx$ and if $s \mathrel{\cal J} sx$, then $s \mathrel{\cal R} sx$.
4. If $s \leqslant_{\cal J} xs$, then $s \mathrel{\cal J} xs$ and if $s \mathrel{\cal J} xs$ then $s \mathrel{\cal L} xs$.
5. A $\mathrel{\cal D}$-class $D$ is regular if and only if there exist
   two elements of $D$ whose product belongs to $D$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: J.-E.  Please carefully read [Enforcement of Quality Standards].  It's a flaggable issue when users, like yourself, frequently answer very low quality questions without context.

Comment: @amWhy I am sorry to say that I often disagree with EQS, especially regarding non-trivial questions, like this one, (even if I agree it could be better stated). I already considered to no longer contribute to this site for this reason. I have absolutely no hard feelings towards the moderators of this site and so if you think this is the best solution, please send me a private e-mail and let's leave it at that.

Comment: Who appointed you to be the trivial/non-trivial God?  This site is for all levels of math.  All users are expected to add context to their questions, not just younger students.  This is a basic undergrad question; seeking someone to do this for them, violating site quality standards.  You enabled such "do it for me" behavior, and in so doing, became part of the problem.  Please challenge yourself and answer good questions, not just low hanging fruit.

Comment: @amWhy I don't claim to be a trivial/non-trivial God, but I have sufficiently knowledge in two domains, finite automata and semigroups, to know when a question is trivial or not. And please refrain to edit my answer by deleting the difficult part of it, namely the conterexample due to  Baer-Levi, to support your opinion that it is a "low hanging fruit".